# How to get items from XML using XMLPULLPARSER in android?

Tags: android

example This is and XML from site

```
<game>
    <root>
        <menu>
            <category>
                <item>aa</item>
                <item>bb</item>
            </category>
        </menu>
    </root>
</game>
```

using parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "category");

how to get the value of the two items? 
or is there more good ways to find go directly your target nodes or items?
this is my codes

```
String search = null;

public static List<String> parse(InputStream stream, String search)
                throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            Util2.XmlParser.search = search;
            try {
                XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,
                        false);
                parser.setInput(stream, null);
                parser.nextTag();
                return readItem(parser);


            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }
        }

        public static List<String> readItem(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();

            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "category");
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                // Starts by looking for the entry tag
                if (name.equals("item")) {
                    System.out.println(parser.getText());
                    System.out.println(parser.getName());

                } else {
                    //skip(parser);
                }
            }  
            return entries;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the sources of "require" method, you'll see that it just checker:

```
public void require(int type, String namespace, String name)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (type != this.type
            || (namespace != null && !namespace.equals(getNamespace()))
            || (name != null && !name.equals(getName()))) {
        throw new XmlPullParserException(
                "expected: " + TYPES[type] + " {" + namespace + "}" + name, this, null);
    }
}
```

You need to walk all path until you reach what you want:

```
<a> -> <aa> -> <aaa>
```

I would suggest you to have reader method for each tag and call them when you are sure you reached the tag.

And this is nice example:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: it does not go directly to your desired target nodes, still you just have to walk all path until you reach it?

Comment: so the first .require should be top most nodes? start from the top nodes ?

Comment: It is not necessity, it's just for insurance. You can put it everywhere.